# onclick and ontouchstart not working on mobile for any element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a website and I use onclick to open the navigation but when I tried it on mobile it didn't work, it just did the :hover animation. I then added ontouchstart to the div and it still doesn't work on mobile. When I tap it it acts like I hover over it. I've looked at a few articles on why it might not work but I can't figure it out. Also any element that uses onclick doesn't work on mobile. Also the js is a separate file (not sure if this would for some reason affect it).

```
<div id="navWrap" onclick="openNav()" ontouchstart="openNav()">
        <div class="navLine"></div>
        <div class="navLine" id="navMid"></div>
        <div class="navLine" id="navBottom"></div>
</div>
```

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}
```

Edit: More code

```
<div id="headWrap">
    <div id="logoWrap"><img src="/static/images/logo.svg" id="logo"></div>
    <div id="headText">Cite Chef</div>
    <div id="navWrap" onclick="openNav()" ontouchstart="openNav()">
        <div class="navLine"></div>
        <div class="navLine" id="navMid"></div>
        <div class="navLine" id="navBottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('navWrap').addEventListener('mousedown', openNav);
    document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[0].addEventListener('click', closeNav);
    document.getElementById('Create').addEventListener('click', create);
    document.getElementById('TInput').addEventListener('click', MYfunctionTwo);
});
```

Comment: what mobile browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried chrome and safari

Comment: Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As implicitly mentioned in the previous answer, we can only guess as far as the current code & context given

Comment: I added more code that would seem relevant I also can provide a url

Comment: I also think that it might be important to reiterate that none of my buttons work on mobile, maybe seeing how I structured my html (ie. script tag at footer) would help. Also thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to some overlapping div's or element on the phone view, you need not add a separate event listener for the phone view click.

Try to inspect the code in the mobile view you might some overlapping element.

Comment: I'm not sure because when I tap it it does the :hover animation and I checked and there are none

Comment: I would be able to help you better If you can share the code.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned on your previous comment, you are testing this on Safari. The inline `onclick` events are going to cause issues in your Web App. This is not supported in some browsers. I recommend using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Simply remove all the inline events and migrate event handling implementations to addEventListener.

```
<div id="headWrap">
    <div id="logoWrap"><img src="/static/images/logo.svg" id="logo"></div>
    <div id="headText">Cite Chef</div>
    <div id="navWrap">
        <div class="navLine"></div>
        <div class="navLine" id="navMid"></div>
        <div class="navLine" id="navBottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
document.getElementById('navWrap').addEventListener('click', openNav);
```

In case you are using a lower version of Safari Mobile. This is good information to have from MDN Web Docs in case you plan on doing event delegation in the future:

> Safari Mobile 7.0+ (and likely earlier versions too) suffers from a
> bug where click events aren't fired on elements that aren't typically
> interactive (e.g. `<div>`) and which also don't have event listeners
> directly attached to the elements themselves (i.e. event delegation is
> being used).

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: I have tried this before, should I add ```document.getElementById('navWrap').addEventListener('click', openNav);``` separate ie. ```<script> document.getElementById('navWrap').addEventListener('click', openNav); </script>```

Comment: no need. just make sure to remove your inline events. bind all events via addEventListener